# Performance issue with NextJs and Google Tag Manager

Tags: performance-testing, google-tag-manager, next.js13, lighthouse, google-pagespeed

[image]

I am encountering an issue while integrating Google Tag Manager into my Next.js project. Is there a more efficient way to integrate Google Tag Manager? Because when I add it in the following way to _document.js:

[image]

my performance score automatically reduces in Lighthouse.

I have tried "beforeInteractive"  "afterInteractive"  "lazyOnload"   at the end of the day they also reduce performance score in Lighthouse

Answer (score 0):

Use defer instead of async to your script tags

Comment: This would benefit from some explanation and / or a reference